# Multiple Virtual Machines on browser

Tags: linux, browser, server, operating-system, virtual-machine

I always wondered how the Hack the box acadamy hosts thousand computers on your browser. If you dont know what i mean this is what it looks like.

[image: Screenshot of HTB - Academy]

So basically you can just press "Spawn Instance" and after a few seconds a new Parrot os boots up in your browser. how did they do that?
I looked through the internet and found something called "VM Ware ESXI". Am i on the right way? Or is it something diffrent?

Im curiously waiting for an answer!
Thanks!

Comment: There's lots of different virtual machine and virtual environment software. How they do it on their server is up to them.

Comment: You can't really tell from the client.

Comment: @Barmar Ok but this answer doesnt help me very much. Do you know any other ways, is the question, not what specificly are they doing.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, it's not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,the opearting-systems seeming to run on web browser are connected by VNC on web.VM Ware ESXI is a hypervistor software of virtual machines which running on their own sever.Actually they seldom provide with high performance and heavy operating-systems will not run there(Linux target can run in minimal status e.g. 100MiB Memorywith sharing CPU) it costs little.

Comment: but if there is a VNC it has to connect to a pc. And i dont think they have a single pc for everyone starting the simulation. so it has to be something like ESXI right?
You said that there are minimal linux systems, but why would it have a input laag like doing it over RDP?